# Why do we represent groups in the category of vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, representation-theory

For any category $\mathcal{C}$ and any object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$ is a group.  Thus, given any group $G$, it makes sense to talk about representing $G$ in $\mathcal{C}$ as automorphisms of some object in $\mathcal{C}$.

Yet, while this makes sense for *any* category, categories of vector spaces (usually over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) seem to have come to play a significantly more prominent role in mathematics than other choices of categories.

My first thought is that this is the case because categories of vector spaces are incredibly well-understood, and so representations on vector spaces can be used to obtain information about the group much more easily than, say, representations on manifolds (i.e. actions by diffeomorphisms).

But is there a more mathematically fundamental reason why categories of vector spaces seem to have a most prominent role in mathematics when it comes to representations of groups?

Comment: Because group theory grew out of the study of linear transformations? (I admit I am not certain this is true, but it has always been my understanding.)

Comment: Of course, the theory of linear representations has been extensively studied. The main reason, I think, is as you said that we understand the category of vector spaces very well. But, the theories of $G$-sets, $G$-spaces, $G$-manifolds, etc has and is also studied a lot. For example, representation of manifolds is a current area of study in low dimensional topology.

Comment: [Historically](https://books.google.com/books/about/Pioneers_of_Representation_Theory.html?id=9ngpAQAAMAAJ), I thought it grew out of number theory and more generally the study of characters of abelian groups, and took on an interesting life of its own. And of course, [Cayley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) was a fan of representations using sets...